# Firebase functions. The function was not triggered

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I try to delete the user`s data using firebase functions after the user deleted his account. I tried this code:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    exports.userDelete = functions.auth.user().onDelete(user => {

        const userPath = admin.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
        console.log("Deleting element " + userPath);
        userPath.remove();
        return null;
    });
```

In the log I see only methodName "UpdateFunction", so the function has never been called since I successfully deleted few users.

I use updated firebase tools 7.8.1
and:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
  },
```

and how I delete user: mAuth.getCurrentUser()).delete()

plz help me to figure out why it doesnt work!

Comment: How you are deleting the user?  BTW you're ignoring the promise returned by `userPath.remove()`, so that might cause problems if the function does execute.

Comment: and how I delete user: mAuth.getCurrentUser()).delete()

Comment: Make sure you actually deployed the function and you can see it in the console.  If it isn't being executed when the user account is deleted, and there are no errors, please contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @Doug Stevenson could you please tell me how to handle that promise?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Yes, I deployed it without any errors, in the console logs I see "UpdateFunction"